Cambiar de estilos con botón mediante clases CSS
Recien empiezo con diseño web espero me tengan paciencia. Mi idea es tener un botón que al presionarlo cambie la clase de main.color y esta a su vez los estilos de CSS para modo claro y obscuro. Pero solamente se queda con los colores del primero he aquí mi código:


const botonAlternarEstilos = document.getElementById('cambiar-modo');
const mainContent = document.getElementById('main-content');
let modoClaroActivado = false;
//Variable para rastrear el estado del modo claro
botonAlternarEstilos.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (mainContent) {
    mainContent.classList.remove('main-content');
  } else {
    mainContent.classList.add('modo-claro');
  }
  modoClaroActivado = !modoClaroActivado;
});
#main-content {
  display: flex;
  backgroun: black;
  z-index: -1;
}

#main-content.modo-claro {
  display: flex;
  background: white z-index: -1;
}
<button id="cambiar-modo">Cambiar modo</button>
<div id="main-content">
  <div class="container">
    datosx
  </div>
</div>




Yo lo haría de la siguiente manera, en principio defino en que modo se inicializara el contenedor que en este caso seria modo-claro y este cambiara al detectar el click del botón como mencionas en tu lógica, quedando de esta manera:


//OBTENEMOS EL BOTON QUE DETONARA EL EVENTO
var botonAlternarEstilos = document.getElementById("cambiar-modo");

//FUCNION QUE ESCUCHA EL CLICK DEL BOTON
botonAlternarEstilos.addEventListener('click', function() {
  //OBTENEMOS EL ELEMENTO AL CUAL SE LE MODIFICARA LA CLASE
  var mainContent = document.getElementById("main-content");
  //SE VERIFICA LA CLASE ACTUAL DEL ELEMENTO
  if (mainContent.classList.contains('modo-claro')) {
    //AQUÍ REEMPLAZAMOS LA CLASE ACTUAL POR LA NUEVA
    mainContent.classList.replace('modo-claro', 'modo-obscuro');
  } else if (mainContent.classList.contains('modo-obscuro')) {
    mainContent.classList.replace('modo-obscuro', 'modo-claro');
  }
});
/*SE DEFINEN LOS ETILOS ESPECÍFICOS PARA CADA CLASE*/

.modo-obscuro {
  display: flex;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  z-index: -1;
}

.modo-claro {
  display: flex;
  background: white z-index: -1;
}
<button id="cambiar-modo">Cambiar modo</button>
<div id="main-content" class="modo-claro">
  <div class="container">
    datosx
  </div>
</div>



Si observas bien accedemos al elemento y validamos la clase actual cada vez que se detecta un click en el botón, con classList.replace lo que hacemos es reemplazar la clase que esta en primer lugar por la segunda, esto hace que cambie los estilos, los cuales están definidos en CSS según la clase.
